# Java method that returns a function?

Tags: java, guava, generic-collections

I'm using [Guava collections' transform functions](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained#Functions), and finding myself making a lot of anonymous functions like this pseudocode:

```
    Function<T, R> TransformFunction = new Function<T, R>() {
        public R apply(T obj) {
            // do what you need to get R out of T
            return R;
        }
    };
```

...but since I need to reuse some of them, I'd like to put the frequent ones into a class for easy access.

I'm embarrassed to say (since I don't use Java much), I can't figure out how to make a class method return a function like this. Can you?

Comment: I think it would help if you narrowed it down a little... give an example of a method you want to write that returns a `Function`, and how you'd use the method.  At the moment, several responders have taken stabs at what they think you want, and it looks to me like they've all missed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think what you want to do is make a public static function that you can re-use throughout your code.

For example:

```
  public static final Function<Integer, Integer> doubleFunction = new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(Integer input) {
      return input * 2;
    }
  };
```

Or if you want to be cool and use lambdas

```
public static final Function<Integer, Integer> doubleFunction = input -> input * 2;
```

Comment: Oh, I *want* to be cool and use lambdas, but stuck pre-Java 8 for this project.

Comment: (This violates Java conventions regarding naming of static fields)

Comment: The non-lambda example is invalid, you should have the method there.

Answer (score 2):

Simply encapsulate it into a class:

```
public class MyFunction implements Function<T, R> {
    public R apply(T obj) {
        // do what you need to get R out of T
        return R;
    }
};
```

Then you can use the class in client code like this:

```
Function<T, R> TransformFunction = new MyFunction();
```

If your functions are related to each other, you could also encapsulate them into an `enum`, because `enum`s can implement `interface`s.

Comment: Please use correct code markup (see the formatting help) rather than awkwardly formatting each line individually.

Comment: Sorry, doing my best on crappy mobile (please do edit).

Comment: Interesting idea on using an `enum`, never would've thought of that on my own.